# recompile less to css with less.modifyVars() and angular

Tags: angularjs, less

I have a list of inputs, created by:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="variable in variables">
    <label>{{ variable.slug }}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="variable.value" ng-change="variableChange()" />
</div>
</div>
```

And a controller:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.variables = [
        {'slug':'background', 'value':'#666'},
        {'slug':'foreground', 'value':'#999'}
    ]
}
```

I'm using the less.js to compile the less in the browser, and I want to be able to re-compile it when the variable changes - something like inside the controller:

```
$scope.variableChange = function() {
    less.modifyVars({ variable.slug : variable.value });
};
```

But I get the error:

```
ParseError: Unrecognised input in preview-style.less on line 102, column 1:
102@variable.slug: variable.value;
```

But if I remove the apostrophes for the variables, I get an angular error:

```
Bad Argument: Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Can anyone help with this?

Edit: here's the less.modifyVars() function if it helps:

```
less.modifyVars = function (a) {
    var b = "";
    for (var c in a) b += ("@" === c.slice(0, 1) ? "" : "@") + c + ": " + (";" === a[c].slice(-1) ? a[c] : a[c] + ";");
    less.refresh(!1, b)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing inside the controller, you must address a scoped property with `$scope`:

```
$scope.variableChange = function() {
    less.modifyVars({ $scope.variable.slug : $scope.variable.value });
};
```

But that will not get this example to work because of the `ng-repeat`.

It would be better to pass the object to the function:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="variable in variables">
    <label>{{ variable.slug }}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="variable.value" ng-change="variableChange(variable)" />
</div>
</div>
```

And then call less like this:

```
$scope.variableChange = function(selectedVariable) {
    less.modifyVars({ selectedVariable.slug : selectedVariable.value });
};
```

Comment: Ah, that seems a better way. However, I get an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' error on the less.modifyVars... line. I changed it to console.log(selectedVariable.slug); and it worked so I guess at least the variable is now available in the controller. I guess the problem is with the less.modifyVars() function. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Solved this now with:   var slug = toString(selectedVariable.slug);
  var value = toString(selectedVariable.value);
  less.modifyVars({ slug : value });